# image map: overlapping areas, highlighting and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, imagemap

Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/6WNQM/1/ which combines normal imagemap HTML, CSS and jQuery 1.9.

The jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#regions_fr').mapster({
        mapKey: 'name',
        singleSelect: true,
        fillOpacity: 0.6,
        fillColor: 'FF0000',
        onMouseover: function (evt) {
            var parts = evt.key.split('-');
            var part = parts[1];
            highlightArea(part);
        }
    });

    $('a').hover(function () {
        var parts = $(this).closest('li').attr('class').split('-');
        var part = parts[2];
        highlightArea(part);
    });
});

function highlightArea(key) {
    $('area[name=part-' + key + ']').mouseenter();
    $('a').removeClass('hover');
    $('li.menu-item-' + key + ' a').addClass('hover');
}
```

You see the map of France which is divided in several (geographical) regions. Overlapping you see some tourist areas that are overlapping 1 or more regions and also overlapping each other.

I'm stuck right now. I want to see specific functionality, but after trying several plugins and CSS techniques, I'm wondering if it's even possible what I want:

- First desired functionality is that the hover over a region highlights the corresponding textlink and vise versa. This works :)
- Second is that the geographical region "Bourgogne" can be hovered, but in IE only the top part can be hovered and becomes highlighted. Any idea?
- Then we have the overlapping part of the two touristregions'. I want them to work as a group when the overlapping part is hovered. In other words, when I click on the overlapping part I want to see the overlapping part being highlighted and the selectbox of "tour-regio 1" and "tour-regio 2" both being checked.

I'm very curious if someone can help me out here, I'm stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The IE problem can be solved by deleting the returns from the coords. Apparently, IE doesn't like returns. Not only the bourgogne area, the tour2 one too. Not sure about the overlapping issue.